# MatrikonOPC Simulation Server on Windows 8.1

Tags: opc

Is it possible to run MatrikonOPC Simulation Server on Windows 8.1.
I am trying using this tutorial ([http://home.hit.no/~hansha/documents/software/documents/MatrikonOPC%20Server%20for%20Simulation%20User%20Manual.pdf](http://tutorial)) to run it and so far there is no success at all.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. I've managed to do so without problems, but check what are your requirements as I think this only supports DA, not UA ...